# Underscore.js function within a function

Tags: javascript, underscore.js

```
  _.filter = function(collection, test) {
    var result = [];
    _.each(collection, function(value) {
      if(test(value)) {
        result.push(value);
      }
    })
    return result;
  };
  _.reject = function(collection, test) {
    var result = [];
    return _.filter(collection, function(value) {
      return !test(value);
    })
  };
```

I'm a bit puzzled by how this works. I have two underscore.js functions defined here in the same scope. If I pass a test array of random nums how does _.filter in _.reject work?

```
var isEven = function(num) { return num % 2 === 0; };
var odds = _.reject([1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6], isEven);
expect(odds).to.eql([1, 3, 5]);
```

For example I test my functions and I get the assert is true but I don't understand how this works

Answer (score 1):

Reject is just reusing some logic that filter accomplishes. It could easily have been written this way:

```
_.reject = function(collection, test) {
  var result = [];
  _.each(collection, function(value) {
    if(!test(value)) {
      result.push(value);
    }
  })
  return result;
};
```

You will notice that the only thing difference between filter and reject is whether we want to keep items when the test is true, or when the test is false.

```
// Creates the function reject
_.reject = function(collection, test) {
  var result = [];

  // Calls filter but hands in a custom callback.
  // Filter iterates each item in the list, and keeps it
  // if test(item) returns true (test is our custom flipResult).
  // Remember that reject does the opposite, it keeps it
  // if test(item) returns false (aka !true).
  return _.filter(collection, function flipResult(value) {

    // The user gave us a test method. We want to keep items
    // that return false when passed to test.
    // If we call _.filter(collection, test) we will get all
    // items that return true when passed to test, but thats not what we want
    // So instead of handing test in directly, we hand in our custom callback
    // The custom callback calls test and flips the result.
    // This means filter will keep all items that return false
    // because our custom callback is flipping the result !test
    return !test(value);
  })
};
```

Answer (score 1):

For example, if your array of numbers are:

```
const nums = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6]
```

and you have a function `isEven` which takes a number and returns `true` if it is even and `false` if it is not even (ie odd):

```
function isEven(num) {
  return num % 2 === 0;
}
```

Then running `_.filter(arr, isEven)` will perform the following logic:

- `arr` takes the name of `collection` and `isEven` takes the name of `test`
- Declare an array called `result`.
- Loop through every number in even

  - For each number (`value`), check if calling `test(value)` gives a result of `true`.
  - If `test(value)` is true, then add the number (`value`) to the end of the `result` array.
  - Go to next number in the array `collection`
- return the `result` array.

So, `filter()` executes the `isEven` function for each number in your array, and if it returns `true`, it is added to a new array (ie: it is kept).

`_.reject()` does the opposite to `_.filter()` - that is, it keeps all elements the callback function returns `false` for. As you know `_.filter()` keeps values it returns `true` for, you can use `_.filter()` by negating the value of the boolean returned by `test(value)`. This way, when `test(value)` returns `false`, you negate it to be `true`, making the `_.filter()` method keep that element. If `test(value)` returns `true`, then you will negate that to be `false`, making the filter method discard of that `value`.

Comment: Thank you. That makes a lot of sense. One thing I'm still confused about is how this executes:     return _.filter(collection, function(value) {
      return !test(value);
    }). 
How does it plug in the function(value) in for the filter function for the test parameter? I guess what I'm asking is how does the function parameter play into the filter function? Since instead of returning when test is true it returns when false. So does the function(value) execute after each time that function filter does for every element?

Comment: @NewAtLearningThis it is executed when you call your `_.reject()` function. So you call your function, it first creates the `var result = [];` (which isn't used) and then it returns the result of calling `_.filter()`. Remeber when you call filter, it will execute the function passed on ever element in your array and only keep those which that function returns `true` for. `_.filter()` will result in an array, which is what is then `return`ed to the caller of `_.reject()`

Comment: @NewAtLearningThis As for how it plugs the function(value){} in for the filter - functions can be passed just like normal values in JS. Imagine calling a function such as `add(1, 2)`. If add looked like `function add(x, y){}` then `x` would take the value of `1` and `y` would take the value of `2`. The same thing is happening with `filter(collection, test)`. The second value `test` takes the value of `function(value){}`, which you can then call within the filter method

Comment: Thank you Nick! This finally clicked for me thanks to your explanation. Makes perfect sense. I was trying to figure this out on my own for a few hours. Appreciate the help again!